# Not able to decode json data in php using curl command

Tags: php, curl

When i am sending data from CURL

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost/HEM/api/items/ -H 'content-type:application/json' --d '{"name":"sdsd"}'
```

it does not decode it in php

I am sending data using mentioned curl request

and trying to decode data but got got nothing in response

```
$str = file_get_contents("php://input");    
$data=json_decode($str);
echo json_encode (array('actual_data'=>$str,'decoded_data'=>$data));
```

This is what is got . decoded data is null.
`{"actual_data":"'{name:sdsd}'","decoded_data":null}`

i want to get name in `$data['name']`

Comment: have you tried to var_dump `$data`?

Comment: yes have check but i got null

Comment: did you dump the $str variable? do your file_get_contents works well?

Comment: When i dump str i got this ```string ''{name:vaibhav}'' (length=16)```

Comment: It is working fine when i am using postman. but when i send data from command line curl it wont work

Comment: Note that your $str contents appears to be wrapped in quotes, which suggests it's being read as a plain string, not a JSON object.

Comment: Yes exactly you got my point but why this is happening? how i can get JSON? Whats wrong in my approach ?

Comment: Is the --d (two hyphens) in your post a typo? It should only be one. https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58#post-applicationjson